# how to catch value of symbol :confirm in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

`<%= f.submit "#{t('next_text')}",  :class => "submit_button" ,:confirm=>'Edit all copies?'%>`

how can I take value(true or false) of :confirm in rails 2.3.5?
I need this value to do some action in controller .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to just add a checkbox to your form whether or not to edit all copies.

If you really need the confirmation box on submit, attach an onSubmit handler to the form

```
<% form_for(@some_model, :html=> {:class => 'edit_confirmation'}) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :edit_all, 0 %> 
  ....
<% end %>
```

The javascript using jQuery:

```
$('form.edit_confirmation').on('submit', function(e) {

  // the hidden field
  var field  = $('input#edit_all');

  if(confirm("Edit all copies?")) {
    field.val(1); 
  } else {
    field.val(0);
  }

  return true;
});
```

In your controller you can get the result with `params[:edit_all]`